Update spacing between Plotly subplots
Is there a way to change the vertical/horizontal spacing between subplots in an existing figure?
I couldn't find anything in the docs or user forum, and the following throws a Bad property error:
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_object as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2, vertical_spacing=0.05)
# ... add subplots to figure

fig.update_layout(vertical_spacing=0.1)


The vertical_spacing isn't just one stored value in the layout, it is used to calculate and set other values, such as plot heights, and x/y axis domains for example. As such, it seems it can only be used on the initial make_subplots call when the Figure object is first configured.

It also depends on what types of plots you have. For example, if you have plots that don't use the traditional cartesian coordinate axes, e.g., pie charts, maps, etc.
